# Why can't I access a method from my code-behind file in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Error when hovering over method signature:
[image: Error when hovering over method signature]

Error message after trying to "Start without debug":
[image: Error message after trying to "Start without debug"]

I've checked everything, the CodeBehind and the Inherits property, so really have no idea what can cause the problem. This is a textbook example, and did everything accordingly, I had once this problem, but can't recall how I resolved it, but it was really something buggy, just re-writing the whole code and it worked. Thank you for your help.

"The name GetProducts() does not exist in the current context"

This is the header of my Listings.aspx file:

`<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Listings.aspx.cs" Inherits="SportsStore.Pages.Listings" %>`

And I want to access the `GetProducts()` method from the code-behind file.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <% foreach (SportsStore.Models.Product item in GetProducts()) {
                    ...
                } %>
        </div>
</form>
```

And here's the Listings.aspx.cs file:

```
namespace SportsStore.Pages {
    public partial class Listings : System.Web.UI.Page {

        private Repository repo = new Repository();

        protected IEnumerable<Product> GetProducts() {
            return repo.Products;
        }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried changing it from `protected` to `public`?

Comment: The `<%foreach` is in Listings.aspx

Comment: Error  displayed: the name getproducts does not exist on the current contex. I tried to set it to public, but did not work.

Comment: I've re-written the whole project and even added `CodeFile="~/Pages/Listing.aspx.cs"` but still nothing.

Comment: Please show us a screenshot of the error that it shows you. Please also include a screenshot of Visual Studio's `Error List`.

Comment: I've added the pics.

Comment: Are you sure the namespaces are the same?

Comment: I would suggest both doing a Build -> Clean Project and a Build -> Rebuild Project, as well as closing and re-opening the form. Sometimes the Intellisense just hasn't caught up to changes in the underlying code.

Comment: How many files called `Listing.aspx.cs` are there in your solution? Is your project really called `9_Pages_Listing.aspx`?

Comment: Tried to clean and rebuild the project and re-open it, but did not work, the build failed. I created another project, I had the same problem, then cleaned and built it, there it worked. It's starting to drive me crazy. :D

Comment: No I even removed GetProducts method from the .aspx file, and build fails with no error message displayed.

Comment: Finally came to the conclusion that ASP.NET simply won't accept every C# language features, like lambda expressions in getters and setters and `out` parameteres.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the source of the problem, I had to re-write the lambda expression in the Repository class, `public IEnumerable<Product> Products { get => context.Products; }` to a regular `get { return context.Products; }` expression. But still don't understand why this made a huge difference.

```
public class Repository {
        private EFDbContext context = new EFDbContext();

        public IEnumerable<Product> Products {
            get {
                return context.Products;
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The best thing to do would be to use a repeater control, and bind the result of get products to the datasource of your repeater, and then handle the data bind event. There are a lot of examples of the repeater control api. Its also a bit safer than using the iteration approach you're using. Try using this article

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8f2zez5.aspx

However this forum has some links that may serve purpose for what you are trying to do.

https://forums.asp.net/t/1139381.aspx?what+are+these+special+tags+and+